# Notification system or library for language runtime versions

Tags: ruby, notifications, programming-languages, version, dependency-management

Is there any service or library available that automatically returns the current stable version of a particular language runtime (java, ruby, ...), preferably as a ruby gem.

The service/library should work similar to dependency services like VersionEye, Gemnasium, etc. but for the base runtimes.

Comment: VersionEye doesn't have this information?

Comment: This could be a feature of version eye in my opinion, although I'm not aware that they provide this information except version information for packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an existing system that does this, other than OS package managers (yum, apt, etc) but these don't always reflect the latest stable for each language. Maintaining a library/gem to do this would be fairly resource-intensive unless there is already a single authoritative source of this information available.

If you don't find any that meet your needs, you can always roll your own:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/',{ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}))

puts doc.content.scan(/current stable version is ([\d\.]+)\./)
```

Output:

```
2.1.2
```

You would have to repeat this technique for any other language.

Comment: I think he's looking for it to return the current version of any language runtime, not just ruby.

Comment: I agree, but since Ruby is the only language tag, I gave an example of retrieving Ruby. You can repeat for any other language once you find the source of the information. Since there's no standard for reporting this information, it would have to be custom scraping for each language.